# Determining user's membership_id for a group given user_id in GroupMe API

Tags: javascript, groupme

Long story short, I am creating a chrome extension for GroupMe that notifies you if a message is posted in a group. The message says who posted it, what they posted, and then allows you to kick or direct message them if you desire.

Everything is working besides being able to kick the person who chatted the message, because that requires the user's `membership_id` and not their `user_id`, as said in their API: https://dev.groupme.com/docs/v3#members_remove

The only reason direct messages worked is because it required their `user_id`, which can be retrieved easily (https://dev.groupme.com/docs/v3#groups_show).

The problem with the above API is that it does not give the regular id of the user. I am having trouble finding a good way to get their id so that they can be removed from the group. Any ideas?

Comment: Hmm... the only place the `membership_id` seems to be provided, per those docs, is in the original `members/add` response. That is strange.

Comment: I know. It should have another way to access them, but nothing is shown.

Comment: I see no other way than putting a server between your users and groupme and then you can only kick those. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Yes it does, thank you @maraca

Answer (score 1):

This may be a late response but I was struggling with the same issue...

The membership id is documented, just not explicitly. In the Members > Update section found here: https://dev.groupme.com/docs/v3#members_update.

To update a member's information. the `membership_id` must be provided. We can see here that the `id` feild is equivalant to the `membership_id`.

```
{
  "id": "MEMBERSHIP ID",
  "user_id": "USER ID",
  "nickname": "NEW NICKNAME",
  "muted": false,
  "image_url": "AVATAR URL",
  "autokicked": false,
  "app_installed": true
}
```

So to remove a user all we need is that `id`. To do so we can just get all members of a group like so:

`GET /groups/:id`

the results of that request will contain a list of all members and contains each members `id` which is their membership id.

For more info see: https://dev.groupme.com/docs/v3#groups_show